# Error 400 Bad Request (Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand)

Tags: http, server, xampp, laravel-5.8

I have API with Laravel 5.8

```
Route::get('/key', function () {
 return response()->json('Hello world');
});
```

When call from POSTMAN or Browser its OK
But when I call from micro controller Error with response :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.31 Server at localhost Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

is there an error in what part?
Public IP or XAMPP or my Program

I'm used XAMPP 7.3.27